# Creating Weather Widgets with JSON and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

What I am trying to achieve is once a user puts the city in an input it will load a Google map for that specific city, and also display the weather data on the selected city.

I am "newish" and am having a hard time finding examples on how to write out the PHP to send off to the HTML and so on and so on.

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="tag-line">
        <h1>... Tag line ...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-head-img"></div>
</header>


<nav>
    <p>... Navigtion goes here ...</p>
</nav>

<main>
    <div class="lefts">
        <div class="panel">
            <h2>Choose a City</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="type here a city name ...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <input type="button" id="get-map" value="Get Map">
                </div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <input type="button" id="get-weather" value="Get Weather">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="feedback">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel weather-container">
            <h2>Weather Today</h2>

            <div class="container">
                <img src="https://www.mikeafford.com/store/store-images/ms02_example_heavy_rain_showers.png" class="initial-img" alt="placeholder">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="rights map-container">
        <div class="panel">
            <h2>City Map</h2>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <p>... footer content ...</p>
</footer>


<!-- Google CDN jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Google Map JavaScript API -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<!-- Handle map here -->
<script src="js/get-map.js"></script>

<!-- Handle weather here -->
<script src="js/get-weather.js"></script>
```

I have commented out a PHP file, from what I think I am trying to achieve. This is the get-map.js

```
// start with $(document).ready(...

// Declare the variables: >>geolocation<<, >>lt<<, >>lg<<. You will need them later in the code

// handle click on Get Map here:
// when the button >>#get-map<< is clicked:

    // Declare the variable >>city<<, fetch the value from text-field, trim it and pass it to variable >>city<<

    // if >>city<< is not empty:

        // send the ajax request for json to:
        // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + city + "&key=yourAPIkey"

        // If request is successful call >>getCity<< otherwise call >>getError<<.
        // These are callback functions belonging to done() and fail() jQuery methods

        // if there is any error message inside the div with class >>.feedback<<, clear it.

    // close if
    // otherwise

        // print the error message to div with the class >>.feedback<< ("please enter the city name...")

    // end of else

// end of click handler



// declare the function >>getCity<< with parameter that stores the object created from json

    // get the value of >>formatted_address<< from the object and pass it to <h2> belonging to 
    // the div with class >>.map-container<<

    // get the values of >>lat<< and >>lng<< from the object and pass them to variables
    // that you declared at the beginning of this document (lt and lg)

    // call the function >>initialize<< and assign its parameters with >>lt<< and >>lg<< values
    // This function is a part of Google Maps JavaScript API. It will draw the map based on the settings 
    // inside the object >>mapOptions<< and based on the given latitude and longitude. This 
    // function will also create the marker

    // clear the input text-field

// end of getCity



// declare the function >>getError<< here (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

    // alert the eventual error

// end of getError




function initialize(latitude, longitude) {

    // basic setting only (this object has many other properties: 
    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls)
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: 8
    };

    // Draws the map using Map()
    var createMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    // Defines your marker position. Position property is the place where marker shows up
    var startPosition = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapOptions.center,
        map: createMap,
        icon: "img/go.png"
    });
}
```

// end of ready

Here is my get-weather.js

```
// start with $(document).ready(...

// Declare the variables: >>geolocation<<, >>lt<<, >>lg<<. You will need them later in the code
// Declare the variable >>collectWeather<< and assign it with empty string. You will need this 
// variable to append weather data coming from json returned by php.


// handle click on Get Weather here:
// when the button >>#get-weather<< is clicked:

    // access div with >>.container<< class inside the div with >>.panel<< class AND display animated gif >>ajax-loader.gif<<

    // Declare the variable >>city<<, fetch the value from text-field, trim it and pass it to variable >>city<<

    // if >>city<< is not empty:

        // send the ajax request for json to:
        // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + city + "&key=yourAPIkey"

        // If request is successful call >>callWeather<< otherwise call >>getError<<.
        // These are callback functions belonging to done() and fail() jQuery methods

        // if there is any error message inside the div with class >>.feedback<<, clear it.

    // close if
    // otherwise

        // print the error message to div with the class >>.feedback<< ("please enter the city name...")

    // end of else

// end of click handler 



// declare the function >>callWeather<< with parameter that stores the object created from json

    // get the value of >>formatted_address<< from the object and pass it to <h2> belonging to 
    // the div with class >>.weather-container<<

    // get the values of >>lat<< and >>lng<< from the object and pass them to variables
    // that you declared at the beginning of this document (lt and lg)
    // concatenate these 2 variables: lt + "," + lg and pass them to 
    // variable >>geolocation<< that is also declared at the beginning of this document

    // use ajax to request php file. Send >>geolocation<< to php file
    // php file will return the json from forecast.io based on >>geolocation<<
    // The ajax request will have 2 callbacks: >>getWeather<< if successful
    // and >>getError<< if it fails

    // clear the input text-field

// end of callWeather



// declare the function >>getWeather<< with parameter that stores php response

    // use variable >>collectWeather<< to append the values of: 
    // >>icon<<, >>temperature<<, >>humidity<< and >>summary<< (part of the json returned by php)
    // everything will need to be parsed in <ul>.

    // access the div with >>.container<< class inside the div with >>.panel<< class AND 
    // pass the value of >>collectWeather<< in it

    // empty >>collectWeather<<

// end of callWeather



// declare the function >>getError<< here (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

    // alert the eventual error

// end of getError
```

// end of ready

Comment: Thanks, in advanced!

Comment: What is your question?